# Fill missing value with with value from another row and if not take the next similar value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I have missing numbers inside the column `materialNumber`. But if a similar `price` is it should take the exactly same `materialNumber`. If more than two `materialNumber` occur with the same `price` it should take the first. If no `materialNumber` is found with the same `price` it should take the next nearst `materialnumber` depending on the price.

Dataframe

```py
   customerId  materialNumber  price
0           1          1234.0    100
1           1          4562.0     20
2           2             NaN    100
3           2          4562.0     30
4           3          1547.0     40
5           3             NaN     37
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "materialNumber": [
        1234,
        4562,
        None,
        4562,
        1547,
        None, 
    ],
    "price": [100, 20, 100, 30, 40, 37],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

import numpy as np
def find_next(x):
  if(x['materialNumber'] == None):
    #if price occurs only once it should finde the next nearst price
    if(x['price'].value_counts().shape[0] == 1): 
      return x.drop_duplicates(subset=['price'], keep="first")
    else:
      return x.iloc[(x['price']-input).abs().argsort()[:2]]

df['materialNumber'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_next(x), axis=1)
```

What I want

```
   customerId  materialNumber  price
0           1          1234.0    100
1           1          4562.0     20
2           2            1234    100 # of index 0: 1234.0, 100 (same value)
3           2          4562.0     30
4           3          1547.0     40
5           3            1547     37 # of index 4: 1547.0, 40 (next similar value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with match rows with missing values per `materialNumber` by rows without missing values and assign values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['materialNumber'].isna()
new = pd.merge_asof(df[m].reset_index().sort_values('price'),
                    df[~m].sort_values('price'), on='price', direction='nearest')

df.loc[m, 'materialNumber'] = new.set_index('index')['materialNumber_y']
print(df)
   customerId  materialNumber  price
0           1          1234.0    100
1           1          4562.0     20
2           2          1234.0    100
3           2          4562.0     30
4           3          1547.0     40
5           3          1547.0     37
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to find the equal or closest price value, then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) your dataframe:

```
# mask to split the DataFrame in NaN/non-NaN for materialNumber
m = df['materialNumber'].isna()

# sort by price (required for merge_asof)
df2 = df.sort_values(by='price')

# fill missing values
missing = pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index().loc[m, ['index', 'price']],
                        df2.loc[~m, ['price', 'materialNumber']],
                        on='price',
                        direction='nearest') # direction='forward' for next only

# update in place
df.update(missing.set_index('index')['materialNumber'])
```

output:

```
   customerId  materialNumber  price
0           1          1234.0    100
1           1          4562.0     20
2           2          1234.0    100
3           2          4562.0     30
4           3          1547.0     40
5           3          1547.0     37
```